# how would I send a monthly email automatically

Tags: civimail, email

I'm looking for suggestions on how to accomplish the following:

Send a regularly scheduled email (monthly or weekly or whatever I choose) based on a specific message template to a specific group without having to go in and schedule it every time.

I'm thinking something like a Weekly Inspirational Quote email or Daily Bible Verse email. The content would change but the basic layout of the email would be the same.

Comment: if you are using Drupal you could look at eileens views token extension which would mean you could manage the content of it in drupal if that made it easier to do. https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_views_token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the CiviRules extension to accomplish this in combination with the Email API extension. Both extensions can be found in the extension directory.

In CiviRules the DailyGroupMembership trigger does what you want, it only does it on a daily basis rather than once a month. You might either come up with some CiviRule conditions to make it run only once a month or even better, adapt the DailyGroup trigger to allow a selection of day/week/month.

Some examples of CiviRules can be found here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+Cookbook