# Sending emails to group promoting a event using CiviMail

Tags: civievent, civimail

I have have created some events, and I would like to send an email to a group to promote each of them individually, and link to information regarding the event. Event tokens are not available in Civimail, since it would have no idea which event you meant.

Has anyone found a semi-automated way to get the info for an event to prefill a message template? I was wondering if using Smarty might work and I could add the event id as a variable, but that's way beyond me at the moment.

I'm not looking to send a scheduled email when the event is created, because it would likely trigger before all details are entered.

One option I have considered using Fancy Tokens to list the events for the next x months. I might need to tweak it though as I'm using Drupal with civicrm_entity to display the event information. But I would prefer to send an email per event, as over time we might have groups specific to event types.

Comment: not sure how much overlap there is here, but this other question touches on some similar issues: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45469/scheduling-repeat-newsletters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send to *Participants* of an event (rather than *Contacts*) then tokens about the event are available.  So if you had an invite list you could look at creating a new not-counted participant status of 'invited', register them as 'invited' and then mail them with event tokens available.  But I don't know how well that fits your scenario.

You can create your own tokens using SearchKit which might be useful here since they don't need to be in a Participant context. If you create a SK for 'next conference event' you can probably create `next_conference_event_title`, `next_conference_event_date` etc using the [SearchKit Tokens extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/sktokens) (not tested).

Comment: I did not know about creating tokens with search kit. Thank you. And I think using an invited status is the right way to go.